# NameError: name not defined when calling function inside of a class

Tags: python, class, oop

I am new to python and writing a simple text based adventure game, I am receiving an error that says **"NameError: name 'bedroom' is not defined"**. I initially had a bunch of function definitions in which case everything was working but decided to group them into classes which is when the error began.

```
class Rooms:
      def start():
        print(".....")
        answer = input(">")
        if "1" == answer
        bedroom() #this is the line the error is coming from

      def bedroom():
        print(".....")
```

Comment: Got it working, thanks to everyone for their help!

Comment: Can you please mark the most helpful answer as accepted, so the community can gauge what is most helpful?

Answer (score 1):

you can do: or add an `self` as parameters of functions, or you can call doing CLASS_NAME.FUNC_NAME()
so you should do:

```
class Rooms:

    def bedroom(self):use self as a parameter
        print(".....") 

    def start(self): #use self as a parameter
        print(".....")
        answer = input(">")
        if "1" == answer:
            self.bedroom() #nothe the use of self
```

And, **NEVER** do this:

```
class Rooms:
      def bedroom():
        print(".....") 

      def start():
        print(".....")
        answer = input(">")
        if "1" == answer
        Rooms.bedroom() #Fixed
```

Comment: According to PEP 20 There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.  which makes your answer out of standard

Answer (score 0):

To invoke a method from within the same class you need to pass the parameter `self` which is used to reference the current class to the method and invoke `bedroom()` in this case it is done like so `self.bedroom()` instead of invoking it like this `bedroom()`:

```
class Rooms:

    def bedroom(self):use self as a parameter
        print(".....") 

    def start(self): #use self as a parameter
        print(".....")
        answer = input(">")
        if "1" == answer:
            self.bedroom() #note the use of self
```

Comment: sorry functional problem my mistake I fixed it